# Xcode 10.2 does not open after installation from App Store

Tags: xcode, xcode10, macos-mojave

When I try to open Xcode 10.2 after installing it from the App Store, it doesn't open. After a while, a dialog box comes with an error "check with the developer to make sure Xcode works with this version of mac os".

Can anyone help? My Mac OS is Mojave 10.14.2

Comment: Which version of mac OS Mojave is installed on your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Xcode 10.2 includes SDKs for iOS 12.2, watchOS 5.2, macOS 10.14.4, and
>   tvOS 12.2. Xcode 10.2 supports on-device debugging for iOS 8 and
>   later, tvOS 9 and later, and watchOS 2 and later. Xcode 10.2 requires
>   a **Mac running macOS 10.14.3 or later**.

Reference:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes/

Comment: After updating the OS, it is working fine. It was my false assumption that App Store won't allow me to download apps that are not compatible with my OS version. Thank you :)